# LocalStorage Clearing when trying to remove a single item

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I'm having an issue with **localStorage**. Whenever the X (e.target.tagName === 'I') icon is clicked to remove one single item from **localStorage**, all of **localStorage** is cleared. What's going on? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Javascript File

```
const todoInput = document.querySelector('#todo-item')
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list')
const form = document.querySelector('form')
const todos = []
const savedTodos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || []

for (let i = 0; i < savedTodos.length; i++) {
  let newTodo = document.createElement('LI')
  newTodo.innerText = savedTodos[i]
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item')
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('I')
  deleteBtn.classList.add('fa-sharp', 'fa-solid', 'fa-square-xmark')
  newTodo.append(deleteBtn)
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo)
}

form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  // e.preventDefault()
  const newTodo = document.createElement('li')
  newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value
  newTodo.classList.add('todo-item')
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('i')
  deleteBtn.classList.add('fa-sharp', 'fa-solid', 'fa-square-xmark')
  newTodo.append(deleteBtn)
  todoList.appendChild(newTodo)

  todoInput.value = ''

  todos.push(newTodo.innerText)
  console.log(newTodo.innerText)

  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
})

function removeFromStorage(itemToRemove) {

  for (let i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    if (todos[i] === itemToRemove) {
      todos.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos))
}

todoList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
// When this line of code is run all local storage is deleted
  if (e.target.tagName === 'I') {
    e.target.parentElement.remove()
    removeFromStorage(e.target.parentElement.innerText)
  } else if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('todo-complete')
  }
  console.log(e.target.innerText)
})
```

Comment: I think you have an issue where you're mixing the `todos` and `savedTodos` variables... I don't see you populating the `todos` variable with your localStorage items at any point, which means that if you reload, you'll be starting off with an empty array again...

Comment: This has seemed to solve the problem. ```const todos = [...savedTodos]```